# Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

Good Evening to all.

I was working with sql server 2008.

Thing i did:

Actually i was noticed that the free space available in C drive reaches below 1 GB .So i thought to Club the D drive with C drive.I had extended the C drive to 18 GB.

Error that Occurs:

Once i finish Extending the drive size i restarted my system.After logon i opened the Microsoft Sql server Management Studio which has multiple database.Every thing works fine except the Database which i have worked recently.When try to expand the table it shows the error as
"**

> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG. A severe error
>   occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be
>   discarded. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

**"
This is how i runned the DBCC runcheck catalog:

> DBCC CHECKDB (Demo) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS

and this is the error which i get while running the above:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Can any one please help me tocome out of this rid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you take a backup of your databases before you decided to make physical changes to the underlying disks the databases were on?

Comment: Ya i have back up...but not the most recent

Comment: Well, this might be an expensive and inconvenient lesson, but it is also quite an important and valuable one. Always pretend that a hardware change is likely to toast the system - if you think in these Debbie Downer terms, you will *always* take a full backup immediately before making such changes.

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand Now i realize my mistake here after i will take back before attempting some hardware thanks...Thanks alot for taking your time replaying

Comment: Aaron's advice is sound; FWIW, though, the error could conceivably have come up even if no hardware changes were made. Thinking that's the cause of the problem is probably misdirected without further investigation.